# Another OS Like Windows server on MAAS Nodes

Tags: maas

Is it possible in near future to have other OS like Windows Servers on MAAS as nodes?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible, if someone is willing to design and implement such a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I will divide your question in two parts:

1. Is it possible to have a Windows Server as a MAAS node?

   Yes, as this is FLOSS (Free/Libre Open Source Software) anything is possible as long as you find enough people willing to develop something.
2. In the near future?

   [Yes](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/11/20/maas-1-7-one-maas-multiple-operating-systems/), MAAS can provision Windows Server 2012 RT/Hyper-V since 2014...

Answer (score 0):

Until you have option to add windows as custom image to your cluster you have another solution:


1) There is a charm "virtme" which can provide VM services

2) You can have Windows on those VMs


https://javacruft.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/virtme/

MIXING PHYSICAL AND VIRTUAL SERVERS WITH JUJU AND MAAS